# Deploy sentry helm in kubernetes cluster

Tags: python, django, postgresql, kubernetes, sentry

I have deployed sentry on kubernetes last week, using this helm chart [stable/sentry](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/sentry).

Pods work fine but i cannot access to the website, it crash every time I access to the endpoint.

I checked logs of the worker, sentry-web and postgres pods and see this.

This is logs of the website pod:

```
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 220, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 713, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 786, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sentry_sdk/integrations/django/__init__.py", line 396, in execute
    return real_execute(self, sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 99, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sentry/db/postgres/decorators.py", line 80, in inner
    raise_the_exception(self.db, e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sentry/db/postgres/decorators.py", line 78, in inner
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sentry/db/postgres/decorators.py", line 22, in inner
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sentry/db/postgres/decorators.py", line 101, in inner
    six.reraise(exc_info[0], exc_info[0](msg), exc_info[2])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sentry/db/postgres/decorators.py", line 94, in inner
    return func(self, sql, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sentry/db/postgres/base.py", line 74, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, clean_bad_params(params))
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: ProgrammingError('relation "sentry_projectkey" does not exist\nLINE 1: ...te_limit_window", "sentry_projectkey"."data" FROM "sentry_pr...\n                                                             ^\n',)
SQL: SELECT "sentry_projectkey"."id", "sentry_projectkey"."project_id", "sentry_projectkey"."label", "sentry_projectkey"."public_key", "sentry_projectkey"."secret_key", "sentry_projectkey"."roles", "sentry_projectkey"."status", "sentry_projectkey"."date_added", "sentry_projectkey"."rate_limit_count", "sentry_projectkey"."rate_limit_window", "sentry_projectkey"."data" FROM "sentry_projectkey" WHERE ("sentry_projectkey"."project_id" = %s  AND "sentry_projectkey"."roles" =  "sentry_projectkey"."roles" | 1) LIMIT 1
```

And this is logs of the postgres pod:

```
ERROR:  relation "sentry_option" does not exist at character 114
STATEMENT:  SELECT "sentry_option"."id", "sentry_option"."key", "sentry_option"."value", "sentry_option"."last_updated" FROM "sentry_option" WHERE "sentry_option"."last_updated" >= '2019-09-13 14:02:49.793126+00:00' 
ERROR:  relation "sentry_monitor" does not exist at character 328
STATEMENT:  SELECT "sentry_monitor"."id", "sentry_monitor"."guid", "sentry_monitor"."organization_id", "sentry_monitor"."project_id", "sentry_monitor"."name", "sentry_monitor"."status", "sentry_monitor"."type", "sentry_monitor"."config", "sentry_monitor"."next_checkin", "sentry_monitor"."last_checkin", "sentry_monitor"."date_added" FROM "sentry_monitor" WHERE ("sentry_monitor"."next_checkin" < '2019-09-13 15:02:50.996171+00:00'  AND "sentry_monitor"."type" IN (2, 3) AND NOT ("sentry_monitor"."status" IN (1, 2, 3))) LIMIT 10000
ERROR:  relation "sentry_scheduledjob" does not exist at character 179
STATEMENT:  SELECT "sentry_scheduledjob"."id", "sentry_scheduledjob"."name", "sentry_scheduledjob"."payload", "sentry_scheduledjob"."date_added", "sentry_scheduledjob"."date_scheduled" FROM "sentry_scheduledjob" WHERE "sentry_scheduledjob"."date_scheduled" <= '2019-09-13 15:02:51.984402+00:00'  LIMIT 101
ERROR:  relation "sentry_authidentity" does not exist at character 288
STATEMENT:  SELECT "sentry_authidentity"."id", "sentry_authidentity"."user_id", "sentry_authidentity"."auth_provider_id", "sentry_authidentity"."ident", "sentry_authidentity"."data", "sentry_authidentity"."last_verified", "sentry_authidentity"."last_synced", "sentry_authidentity"."date_added" FROM "sentry_authidentity" WHERE "sentry_authidentity"."last_synced" <= '2019-09-13 14:02:56.685172+00:00'
```

And the worker pods:

```
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sentry/tasks/options.py", line 36, in sync_options
    for option in Option.objects.filter(last_updated__gte=cutoff_dt).iterator():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 220, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 713, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 786, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sentry_sdk/integrations/django/__init__.py", line 396, in execute
    return real_execute(self, sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 99, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sentry/db/postgres/decorators.py", line 80, in inner
    raise_the_exception(self.db, e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sentry/db/postgres/decorators.py", line 78, in inner
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sentry/db/postgres/decorators.py", line 22, in inner
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sentry/db/postgres/decorators.py", line 101, in inner
    six.reraise(exc_info[0], exc_info[0](msg), exc_info[2])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sentry/db/postgres/decorators.py", line 94, in inner
    return func(self, sql, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sentry/db/postgres/base.py", line 74, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, clean_bad_params(params))
ProgrammingError: ProgrammingError('relation "sentry_option" does not exist\nLINE 1: ...ion"."value", "sentry_option"."last_updated" FROM "sentry_op...\n                                                             ^\n',)
SQL: SELECT "sentry_option"."id", "sentry_option"."key", "sentry_option"."value", "sentry_option"."last_updated" FROM "sentry_option" WHERE "sentry_option"."last_updated" >= %s 
15:09:24 [ERROR] celery.worker.job: Task sentry.tasks.options.sync_options[e1684c22-6593-48d9-94c7-2c47ee7fc397] raised unexpected: ProgrammingError(u'ProgrammingError(\'relation "sentry_option" does not exist\\nLINE 1: ...ion"."value", "sentry_option"."last_updated" FROM "sentry_op...\\n                                                             ^\\n\',)\nSQL: SELECT "sentry_option"."id", "sentry_option"."key", "sentry_option"."value", "sentry_option"."last_updated" FROM "sentry_option" WHERE "sentry_option"."last_updated" >= %s ',) (data={u'hostname': 'celery@teq-sentry-worker-6ddfb9658c-gbkth', u'name': 'sentry.tasks.options.sync_options', u'args': '[]', u'internal': False, u'kwargs': '{}', u'id': 'e1684c22-6593-48d9-94c7-2c47ee7fc397'})
```

Comment: Looks like the DB hasn't been initialized with all the requisite tables, like `sentry_option`, etc. That helm chart has a hook called `db-init`, and in the README it says you need to be using Helm >= 2.3 to make the hooks work. Can you post the versions of things (chart, Helm, kubectl, etc.) that you're using?

Comment: This is my helm version: 
```Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.14.0", GitCommit:"05811b84a3f93603dd6c2fcfe57944dfa7ab7f", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.14.0", GitCommit:"05811b84a3f93603dd6c2fcfe57944dfa7ab7f", GitTreeState:"clean"}```

Comment: If you do `kubectl get job` do you see the `<RELEASE_NAME>-db-init` ran successfully?

Comment: I don't see any job @@.

Comment: Any chance you ran `helm install stable/sentry --no-hooks` or installed the chart with an older version of Helm before later upgrading to `v2.14.0`? When I run the basic `helm install stable/sentry` it clearly starts to do the init-db job (in my setup it gets stuck pending since it apparently needs 3GB memory and this is a small minikube setup, but it is definitely trying to run).

Comment: I think the problem is the jobs does not run so migrations command not execute. I have deleted and deploy again but it still not run the jobs. My worker node have 2 cores and 4GB ram

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solve.
Thank you everyone for your help. The problem is I'm not have enough RAM in order to run the migration script, so I upgrade the VPS to 8GB RAM and then it's work.

Because the migration script have some memory leak so pods need at least 4GB free memory to run. See this [comment](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry/issues/11302#issuecomment-450982634) on Github

Answer (score 5):

you must migrate schema's manually,
run the following command to migrate your schema:

`kubectl exec -it <your-pod-name> sentry upgrade`

Comment: When i run the above command i get the below result 
Do you have any other solution?    
kubectl --namespace sentry exec -it sentry-web-5f9f8b668-nkmwt  sentry upgrade
07:48:45 [WARNING] sentry.utils.geo: settings.GEOIP_PATH_MMDB not configured.
07:48:47 [INFO] sentry.plugins.github: apps-not-configured
Running migrations for default
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, nodestore, replays, sentry, sessions, sites, social_auth
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
Creating missing DSNs
Correcting Group.num_comments counter

Answer (score 0):

Faced a similar issue. In our case, we have enabled ingress (Nginx). And this setting conflict with service.type: `LoadBalancer`, just change it to `ClusterIP` and do the clear setup again.

TLDR - DB init starts on "post-install" event (all deployed components is in a ready state) but in case of LoadBallancer, ingress and `--wait` combination the web Service must have assigned IP (https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/using_helm.md#helpful-options-for-installupgraderollback). For some reason it wasn't true and web service always returns `false`. After change the service setting from `LoadBalancer` to `ClusterIP` the issue is gone.